# setting Back color of a disabled combo to white color

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

hi
I have a combo box which can enabled and disabled at run time.now i needed to make make the back color constant even if it is enabled or disabled.any one can help me?

Comment: Refer to following [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/disabledcombodisplay.aspx)

Comment: This probably comes closest to a working solution; just the Dispose at the end of the DrawItem code bothers me.

Answer (score 4):

I found following solutions.

**Solution 1:**

set the dropdownstyle to be `"DropDownList"` when disabled and then reset it to `"DropDown"` when you enabled the control

```
combobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

**Solution 2:**

Go here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22454/ReadOnly-ComboBox

First solution work for me and 2nd solution u can try it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
comboBox1.DropDownHeight = 1;
comboBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyDown);
comboBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyPress);
comboBox1.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyUp);
```

Now in each of this handlers just set e.Handled = true

```
void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Now when you have to function it as a Enabled just remove the handlers and set the `DropDownHeight`

```
comboBox1.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyDown);
comboBox1.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyPress);
comboBox1.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyUp);
```

Comment: What about mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

If this is WinForms then set the BackColor Property to whatever you want it to be.

As stated below this does NOT work.

Comment: Won't work, if disabled the ComboBox is automatically drawn grayed to _show_ it's disabled.

Comment: You are absolutely right - teach me to check more carefully.  What works for a TextBox does not work for a ComboBox....

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you are after, [Googling](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdesigner/thread/0004035e-4f1d-4b16-bd97-6123c209fe2f) has found me a potential solution:

If what you're after is to get the combobox in a disabled state (unchangable, but looking the same as when enabled), then quickly setting the Enabled property from true, to false, then back again on Enter achieves it, although in a somewhat hacky manner:

```
bool isDisabled = true;
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(isDisabled)
    {
        comboBox1.Enabled = false;
        comboBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```